# Compilation error when compiling php extension

Tags: php, c, visual-studio-2008, compilation, php-extension

I'm following [this tutorial](http://blog.slickedit.com/2007/09/creating-a-php-5-extension-with-visual-c-2005/) to build a hello-world type extension for php, and compiling with visual studio 2008 express on Windows7. When I build, I get these errors:

- 1 has to do with allocation a constant array of size 0
- the others seem to have to do with time.

But I'm not sure what they mean fully or how to fix them.

```
Compiling...
stdafx.cpp
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\sys/stat.inl(44) : error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\sys/stat.inl(49) : error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\sys/utime.inl(39) : error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\sys/utime.inl(44) : error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\sys/utime.inl(49) : error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\sys/utime.inl(78) : error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\wtime.inl(37) : error C2664: '_wctime32' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const time_t *' to 'const __time32_t *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\wtime.inl(43) : error C2664: 'errno_t _wctime32_s(wchar_t *,size_t,const __time32_t *)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const time_t *' to 'const __time32_t *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\time.inl(32) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'time_t' to '__time32_t', possible loss of data
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\time.inl(32) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'time_t' to '__time32_t', possible loss of data
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\time.inl(38) : error C2664: '_ctime32' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const time_t *' to 'const __time32_t *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\time.inl(44) : error C2664: 'errno_t _ctime32_s(char *,size_t,const __time32_t *)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const time_t *' to 'const __time32_t *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\time.inl(51) : error C2664: '_gmtime32' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const time_t *' to 'const __time32_t *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\time.inl(57) : error C2664: '_gmtime32_s' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const time_t *' to 'const __time32_t *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\time.inl(64) : error C2664: '_localtime32' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const time_t *' to 'const __time32_t *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\time.inl(69) : error C2664: '_localtime32_s' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const time_t *' to 'const __time32_t *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
C:\Program\VS2008\VC\include\time.inl(81) : error C2664: '_time32' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'time_t *' to '__time32_t *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look at those lines in the files, then at the definition of STATIC_ASSERT,those are actually STATIC_ASSERT fails, checking that standard type names match the size specific 32 bit type names. seems to me you have a mismatch between 32 bit and 64 bit compiles somehow.

the business with cannot allocate an array of size 0 is a trick used in the static assert macro. not very informative.